# How to use System.Json in non-Silverlight .NET apps ( .NET 4.0/ WPF)

Tags: .net, wpf, silverlight, json

My Silverlight application ViewModel has many Json parsing dependencies on to System.Json.dll. I got to know that this dll is not available in regular .NET. My Silverlight app is in production and now I am planning to port the same to WPF, and I am got it ported with out any code change to WPF except the places where I am parsing the Json like below (Pasting just some sample code, I got 100s of lines of similar Json parsing code snippets).

```
  JsonValue result = JsonObject.Parse(data);
  JsonArray movieList = result.SelectToken("movie") as JsonArray;
```

I can use some other mechanism to parse it or use Json.NET like solutions, but just wondering if there is any easy solution out there, that is a .NET port of System.Json.dll. Then I don't need to change 50 of my ViewModel .cs files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got a nice implementation https://github.com/JeffreyZhao/System.Json , which is 100% compatible with System.Json.dll worked like a charm! I didn't need any code change in my Silverlight VM to port to WPF.

Answer (score 1):

Although this will most likely mean some changes to your deserialization code but the [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com) framework is available on WP7, Silverlight and WPF.

Comment: Yep, I know we can rebuild it in many ways, but my point is to not touch the VM code I have.